# In android studio, the AVD emulator opens but doesn't run. Please see the details

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intel, haxm

I have installed Intel haxm properly, hardware virtualisation is enabled. The window for AVD opens and a phone is displayed on screen, but nothing else happens (the phone doesn't run). These are the messages that come up on screen:

emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 1024 MB
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the amount of RAM that is being used by your AVD to equal or lower than what is set in  your HAXM configuration.  Your AVD is at 1536 and HAXM is 1024.  Set your AVD to 768, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

My AVD was at 1536 MB and HAXM was at 1 GB.  I changed the AVD to 1 GB.  It failed with the above messages.  I looked at the AVD and it had changed back to 1536 MB.  I changed the AVD to 768 MB.  It worked.